# JSON object with "NULL" value gets changed to bank value when sending via HTTP request to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ajax, http

I have the following object:

```
  var payload = {
    someProperty: null
  };
```

I send the object to an API endpoint using HTTP.

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: nodeHost + ":" + agentWebPort + "/assignDisposition/",
    data: payload,
    beforeSend: function(request) {
      request.setRequestHeader("session", cookieSessionID);
      request.setRequestHeader("user", cookieUsername);
    },
    success: function(response) {;
    } //end success
  });
```

On the (Node.js) server, I view the data from the HTTP request as follows:

```
console.log(payload);
```

And to my surprise, this is the output:

> {someProperty: '' }

Even though my property value originated as NULL it is an empty string once it gets to the server.

Is this normal behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I try to read Request's body by asp.net

**ajaxText.apsx**

```
    string req_txt;

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream))
    {
        req_txt = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    Response.Write(req_txt); var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

**javascript**

```
   var payload = {
        someProperty: null
    };


    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {   // XMLHttpRequest.DONE == 4
           if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
               console.log("XMLHttpRequest : " + xmlhttp.responseText);
           }
           else if (xmlhttp.status == 400) {
              alert('There was an error 400');
           }
           else {
               alert('something else other than 200 was returned');
           }
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("POST", "/Test/ajaxTest.aspx", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(payload));
```

**XMLHttpRequest reulst was {"someProperty":null}**

[image]

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Test/ajaxTest.aspx",
        data: payload,
        success: function (response) {;
            console.log("$.ajax : " + response);
        } 
    });
```

**jquery ajax's result was someProperty:''**

[image]

you can see the difference in the results.

jquery would serialize the json object to string and change from null to "" in the process.